# How to download a blogger rss feed in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, rss

I am looking for a script that takes url of an rss feed, and outputs the contents of all posts into one html file. Is there an existing example that does it? Google searches mostly give scripts that download all enclosers, not the html/body of each post, which is what I am after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading RSS feed is done with, say, `Net.WebClient`. As the RSS feed itself is XML, it can be manipulated easily enough. Powershell's got `ConvertTo-HTML` that makes conversion to HTML simple. Getting news headlines from Google News is done like so,

```
$webclient = new-object system.net.webclient
$rssFeed = [xml]$webclient.DownloadString('http://news.google.com/?output=rss')
$rssFeed.rss.channel.item | Select-Object title -First 5 | ConvertTo-Html
```

Use `Out-File` to save the HTML into a whatever a file you wish to.

#### Edit:

Picking description is simply done by using `Select-Object`:

```
$rssFeed.rss.channel.item | select title,description -first 5
```

To check what kind of fields there are, use `Get-Member` or read the XML feed directly:

```
$rssFeed.rss.channel.item[0] | gm -MemberType property
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me started, but how would I specify the format so that output contains both the title and description (body of a blogger post, already is in html format)?

Comment: @Joe It would be helpful to have input and expected output in your question.

Comment: I was looking for a way to retrieve multiple fields, so the updated examples answers it, thanks for the help.